# Form field doesn't exist after from has been submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I work on some old feature in one of the pages in the system. There is a table with input fields. Once user enter data and click save new rows will be added as well as data being saved for existing rows. Object contains just the text. So my guess is that innerHTML won't be recognized as the part of the DOM. Is there a way in JS to append the text to the table? Here is my JS:

```
obj //variable that has HTML elements for new rows

for (r = 0; r < obj.length; r++) {
    insRowIndex++;
    newRow = parTable.insertRow(insRowIndex);
    newRow.innerHTML = obj[r];//returning empty string...
}
```

After entering data in new row (that was added) and click save I was getting error message from the server side:

```
Element gd_datenew1 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope.
```

I have checked the code and this error was indicating to `form` object. New field `gd_datenew1` doesn't exist in the form fields. Even this field exist on the screen and data was entered but field was never submitted in the form. If I reload my page and enter data in that field everything works fine data is successfully saved. Here is JS code that is used to submit the form fields:

```
var param = document.forms[0];

try{
    http('POST', 'myApp.cfc?method=UpdateRecordAJAX', saveResp, param);
}catch(err) {
    alert('Error!')
}
```

I'm not sure why that field is not submitted with the rest of the fields. Do I have something wrong in my code where new rows are being added? If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: Is the field a checkbox?  They are not submitted with the form if they are not selected.

Comment: @Miguel-F There is few input fields text & select, no checkbox fields.

Comment: _"So my guess is that innerHTML won't be recognized as the part of the DOM"_ - stop guessing, and use dev tools to _verify_ instead ...

Comment: Doesn't seem like an error w/front-end JS, but w/server-side method `UpdateRecordAJAX` not updating the object/model to add the new members/rows dynamically. Trying to POST data with a `gd_datenew1` field before updating the server-side model to include it won't work as it has nowhere to go. Or, if the server is being asked to read back `gd_datenew1` from a database or server-side object that hasn't yet been updated to contain that field it won't work. Since it works after refresh the object/model gets updated eventually. Maybe an async issue? Or doing things out of order?

Comment: @mc01 Element gd_datenew1 is part of the form scope. All what I do on the back end is looping over form scope. The problem is that field is never submitted in the form. I did try to append that to my param variable and in that case gd_datenew1 was passed in the form scope.

Comment: @espresso_coffee without more details we are all just guessing here. Share your code that contains the form fields.

Comment: Agreed @Miguel-F. Can you post the affiliated HTML?  
Also what do you use to serialize your form fields?